# Reflection on internal, overload and with ref parameters method

Tags: .net, reflection

How to obtain a reference to the method System.Web.Configuration.MachineKey.GetEncodedData using .net v1.1?

With the following code it returns null:

```
Type t = typeof(System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase)
    .Assembly
    .GetType("System.Web.Configuration.MachineKey");

MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("GetEncodedData",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, 
    null,
    new Type[] { typeof(byte[]), typeof(byte[]), typeof(int), typeof(int) },
    new ParameterModifier[0]
);
```

Comment: I think you're missing `BindingFlags.Instance`.

Comment: @Steven: Not if the aim is to call a static method.

Comment: Are you *definitely* running in .NET 1.1? And does the method definitely *exist* in .NET 1.1?

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's true. I assumed it was an instance method, but I have no way to check this, since .NET 1.1 is not installed on my machine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, running .NET 1.1 and checked with reflector that the method exists. It is internal. The signature is: "internal static byte[] GetEncodedData (byte[], byte[], int, ref int)"

Comment: Method "internal static void EnsureConfig()" is there also and I'm able to get a reference to it. It seems a problem with the "by ref" parameter. Cannot find a way to do it in .net 1.1.

Comment: @PAC: Ah, right. Will see what I can do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it sounds like the problem is that there's no equivalent of [`Type.MakeByRef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makebyreftype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET 1.1.

You *may* be able to use `Type.GetType("System.Int32&")` to get that:

```
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("GetEncodedData",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, 
    null,
    new Type[] { typeof(byte[]), typeof(byte[]),
                 typeof(int), Type.GetType("System.Int32&" },
    new ParameterModifier[0]
);
```

Alternatively, you could always create your *own* method (which you can find using just `GetMethods` for example) with a `ref int` parameter, and use *that* parameter type. Icky, but...

All of this feels very brittle to start with, of course. I assume you've got a *really good* reason for wanting to invoke an internal method on a pretty-much-obsolete version of the framework...

Comment: Nice one! It returns the reference to the method when using the last parameter with Type.GetType("System.Int32&").